# Magento search request in admin is urlencoded

Tags: magento-1.9, url, search, character-encoding, utf-8

in magento admin panel, in latest search request, cyrilic requests displayed url encoded/ Such as %D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B3%D0%B8. How i can resolve this issue? please help.

Comment: Are you sure this is a search term and not one of those spooky injections attack? Nothing will happen to your store if option 2.

Comment: Its definitely frontend search term by some bots - your search term's decoded string is "угги" which is not part of any admin request.

Comment: This cyrilic search terms. I need to dispalay %D1%83%D0%B3%D0%B3%D0%B8 as "угги"

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that your string's encoding is being changed by an Apache redirect. Adding a NE (No Escape) flag could help, as demonstrated in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14479403/htaccess-redirect-urls-with-utf-8-chars